# How to get Azure APIM health check & details

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, health-check

We are using Azure APIM in production.

We are developing service detail page where if it is not available, will update the page.

So i would like to know how to check health check for APIM?

In most of the case, it will be case of 502/503/504 http status code.

Answer (score 2):

While at the request level, you could get a `5xx` response for several reasons like the incorrect policies or backend failures.

For APIM itself, there are regional status endpoints that you can use which are described in the [APIM multi-region deployment doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-deploy-multi-region#-use-custom-routing-to-api-management-regional-gateways). Here is how it looks for reference

```
https://<service-name>-<region>-01.regional.azure-api.net/status-0123456789abcdef
```

Example from the docs

```
https://contoso-westus2-01.regional.azure-api.net/status-0123456789abcdef
```

Comment: Thanks Pramod for your reply. so you mean to say to check the current status of our APIM service, as we are using custom domain, we should configure Traffic manager and then i should the the status ?

Comment: @ManishJoisar You can also get details in the response body by using following URL: https://<service-name>-<region>-01.regional.azure-api.net/internal-status-0123456789abcdef